# App not registering mobile install

Tags: facebook, ads

I am trying to set up Facebook Mobile Install Ads. My app does not use facebook for any other reason.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Setup/added facebook sdk
2. In appdelegate:

`#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>`

and in applicationdidfinishinglaunching...

`[FBSettings publishInstall:[FBSession defaultAppID]];`

3.Created a facebook application as iOS native app

My facebook app has not registered any facebook app installs from the tests I have done on my device. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I neglected to include the Security framework. It didn't pop up any errors but that was the issue in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch, but you probably have to allow your app Facebook permissions. If you have ever tried Friendcaster, Fast for Facebook, Seesmic, or another alternative FB app, you can see that you have to grant the app permissions to access your Facebook account. It seems that the developer has an app on Facebook, just like a game. That internal Facebook app is given permissions to access the account, and then the FB client accesses the account via the app. Like I said, this is only a hunch, but it makes sense.

Comment: No going through the facebook documentation it makes it very clear that granting permissions is unnecessary as I do not use the facebook sdk for any reason other than this one line of code. Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0):

It *is* likely working. There is a "trick" to seeing that your app is working.

Yes, you can test "App Installs" on the Simulator or on your device...but...you might not see them on the Facebook Dashboard.

Instead, first go to the INSIGHTS tab reached from the left menu on the App Dashboard. You may see App Installs here - but you might not.

Second, if you don't see any live data for App Installs, look at the section called "APP LAUNCHES." That can be used as a surrogate indicator that your app is working.

Third, if you don't see live data for "App Launches" - look at the date range. Change the date range to extend to TOMORROW's date. Give Facebook 1-2 minutes to update with your data. At that point, now you can see that live App Launches are occurring - and thus will know that your connection to FB is working.